# how to mimic derived to base pointer auto cast?

Tags: c++

I have a `Base` class and a `Derived` class. Both have their own non-static data member and both have to have standard layout. So I can't inherit `Derived` from `Base` and have to declare then separately. I know I can define an `operator Base&` in the `Derived` class so that `Base& base = derived` works. Is there any way to make `Base* pBase = pDerived` works too (without an explicit cast)?

Comment: I guess you could override `operator&` in `Derived` and have it return `Base*`.

Comment: @TFM Sorry, bad example. I edited the question.

Comment: Ok, I see now. I honestly don't think it can be done. You would either need an out-of-class `operator=` or out-of-class conversion operator, and neither of those exist.

Comment: @J.Doe Just to make sure, you cannot inherit because of this specific Standard Layout requirement: "All non-static data members have the same access control"?

Comment: I would like to see some example code that shows the problem. It's not clear just from the text.

Comment: @SkepticalEmpiricist Derived class can't have non-static data member.

Comment: @Dialecticus actually the example in the answer is quite clear.

Comment: Roger that @J.Doe, thanks.

Comment: You cannot implicitly convert unrelated pointers. So you will need to adapt all your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a proxy object to represent a pointer:

```
struct Base;
struct Derived;

struct Ptr
{
    Ptr(void* ptr) : ptr(ptr) { }

    operator Base*() { return reinterpret_cast<Base*>(ptr); }
    operator Derived*() { return reinterpret_cast<Derived*>(ptr); }

private:
    void* ptr;
};

struct Base
{
    Ptr operator&() { return Ptr(this); }
    operator Derived&() { return *reinterpret_cast<Derived*>(this); }
};

struct Derived
{
    Ptr operator&() { return Ptr(this); }
    operator Base&() { return *reinterpret_cast<Base*>(this); }
};

void bar(Base*)
{ }

void foo()
{
    Derived derived;
    Base* base1 = &derived;
    Base& base2 = derived;
    bar(&derived);
}
```

This formal solution should be carefully analyzed for UB if used.

Comment: `&` operator is not the only one that I concerned. I change the example to elaborate my intention.

Comment: Probably I don't understand what you want. I omitted `operator Base&()` because you mentioned it in your question. I edited my answer to make it explicit.

Comment: I guess it can't be done. What I want is that I can give a `Derived*` pointer anywhere that requires a `Base*` pointer, as if `Derived` is public inherited from `Base`.

Comment: If you have `void bar(Base*)` you can call it like `bar(&derived)`. Edited my answer once again.

Comment: @J.Doe I guess you could make sure "anywhere" is always a template, and leverage SFINAE on traits on the template type parameter to allow this relation.

Comment: @J.Doe, `std::launder` should probably be used here, but I am not sure. If you use this solution in a real code, please carefully analyze possible UB  involved.